# Conditionally apply css class to div in React ternary

Tags: reactjs, ternary-operator

I'm mapping over a data object in React, and need to be able to conditionally apply a class to a div if `item.lead === true` for either `item.profile` or `item.noprofile`. My current implementation is grabbing user data, but not sure how to apply a class with my current setup:

**React Profile**

```js
<li key={i} className={classes.member}>
      <a href={`mailto:${item.email}`}>
        {item.profile ? (
          <img
            alt={item.name}
            className={classes.profile}
            src={item.profile}
          />
        ) : (
          <div className={classes.noprofile}>
            <span className={classes.initials}>
              {item.firstName}
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
        <div className={classes.details}>
          <div>
            {item.firstName} {item.lastName}
          </div>
          <span>{item.title}</span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
```

**JSS class that needs to be applied if a user is a lead (`item.lead`)**

```js
   lead: {
    "&:after": {
      content: `'LEAD'`,
      top: "5px",
      position: "relative",
      zIndex: "-1",
      fontSize: "10px",
      padding: "5px 4px 2px 4px",
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
className={classes.profile + (item.lead && ' lead' || '')}
```

Comment: So, I see what you're trying to do here, but the as the logic is now, it says if user.profile has a value, show the user image, else show div with user name and title. I need to apply that `lead` class with a pseudo class to any profile if the users `lead` field is `true`. So there may need to be a 3rd option that if user profile has `lead: true`, add class `lead` to `className={classes.profile}` or `className={classes.noprofile}`

Answer (score 0):

@Bhojendra's logic was close, but I discovered the logic needed to be as follows:

-for profiles with images: `(item.lead === true &&` ${classes.profilelead}`) || ""`

-for those without: `className={classes.noprofile + ((item.lead === true &&` ${classes.lead}`) || "")}`